# set folder into directory

Tags: php, file-upload

I am creating an apps for uploading file into the system but here, i am facing a problem. the folder have been create properly as i want but when i click the upload button, the file is not save in the folder as i set as a target.. below is my syntax.

```
$id=$_SESSION['topic'];

$target_path = mkdir("doc_student/$id", '0777');
$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)){
     echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
}else{
    echo "Error during uploading this file";
}
```

Comment: The problem you're having results in because the return value of [`mkdir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#refsect1-function.mkdir-returnvalues) is boolean and not a string. So you end up with something like `$target_path = true . basename($FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);`

Answer (score 2):

[mkdir()](https://www.php.net/mkdir) Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. if you assign `$target_path` to `mkdir` function then variable becomes boolean. Try this,

```
 $target_path = "doc_student/$id";
 if(!is_dir($target_path)){
    mkdir($target_path, '0777');
 }
```

instead of

```
$target_path = mkdir("doc_student/$id", '0777');
```

Answer (score 1):

`mkdir()` retuns a `boolean` if it has success, not the created folder's path, you must use another syntax:

```
mkdir("doc_student/$id", '0777');
$target_path = "doc_student/$id";
```